# Firefox userContent do not apply

Tags: css, firefox

As I am very short sighted, and after trying several solutions, I want to customize Firefox to see web pages with my own settings.
I defined a 'userContent.css' file placed in chrome/ directory. The CSS seems to apply to some items (options, some buttons) but not to all. Here is a simple HTML test case. I want the imputs to have a deep blue background, and a white foreground color;

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">
  </head>
  <body>
    <br/><br/>
    <form action='/~moumou/perso/books/books.rvt?action=add' method='GET' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
      Titre : <input name='titre'><br/>
      Prénom <input name='prenom'><br/>
      Nom <input name='nom'><br/>
      <input type='submit'>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The imput boxes appear with a white background and black foregrnad color.
The userContent.css file is as follow :

```
select {
    background : #001144 !important;
    color: white !important;    
}
button {
    background-color: #001144 !important;
    color: white !important;
}
option {
    background-color: #001144 !important;
    color: white !important;
}
select option {
    background-color: #221144 !important;
    color: white !important;
}
div input {
    background-color: #001144 !important;
    color: white !important;
}
input[type="text"],textarea {
    background-color: #001144 !important;
    color: white !important;
}
input[type="button"] {
    background-color: #001144 !important;
}
form input {
    background-color: #001144 !important;
    color: white !important;
}
input {
    background-color: #001144 !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```

As you can see, I tried several ways to force the input to have blue bg and white fg.

Why these settings do not apply to inputs, and some do ?

Many thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly where your example goes wrong, but here are some general pointers:

- You can combine several selectors into one rule, so instead of creating a long list of form elements with duplicated rules for the colors of each, you can list the selectors and declare the colors once. You don't need to qualify each form element selector with `div`, `form` etc.
- Browsers’ styling of form controls is a mix of CSS and the default look of form controls on the operating system you're on. Most things should be able to override, but sometimes it can be tricky. One of the tricks for buttons and inputs to accept CSS is to affect the `border` property—it seems to force the browser to "listen" to the CSS.
- Likewise, browsers have default CSS for the form controls, so they will not automatically inherit things like font size or font family. You can set `font: inherit` (as an example) if you want to override this.
- Other than that, your stylesheet *should* work, as user stylesheets with `!important` should override any author- or user agent stylesheets.

Here's a sample of your code, rewritten as a  single selector list, and with an added border. I've used a negation of the type attribute selector, in order to avoid styling checkboxes and radio buttons. If you want the same color for those, you can switch that part to a plain `input` selector.

```
select,
option,
button,
input:not([type="checkbox"]),
input:not([type="radio"]),
datalist,
textarea {
  font-size: inherit !important;
  background-color: #001144 !important;
  color: white !important;
  border: .05em solid red !important;
}
```

I have put up an example here: http://jsbin.com/bosidoz/4/edit?html,css,output – feel free to try and copy/paste from that, and comment if you have any further questions. Let me know how it goes & Good luck!

Comment: Waowww !! What an answer !! Many many thanks to be so clear and so helpfull !! Thanks again !